# Mails received with same message id every 15 - 20 seconds

Tags: postfix, spam, spamassassin

I have SpamAssassin integrated on my postfix mail server via 'Amavisd-new'.

The problem that I am facing is that I am receiving same email every 15 second from same sender with same message-ID on my production mail servers, following are my postfix logs:

```
Oct 25 01:11:02 g2t0433g postfix/smtpd[6497]: connect from webmail.warwick.net[204.255.24.104]
Oct 25 01:11:02 g2t0433g postfix/smtpd[6497]: 2EAAF23004C: client=webmail.warwick.net[204.255.24.104]
Oct 25 01:11:02 g2t0433g postfix/cleanup[6579]: 2EAAF23004C: message-id=<CE130ED7-D498-4461-B076-E3B8AB55B462@warwick.net>
Oct 25 01:11:02 g2t0433g opendkim[17677]: (unknown-jobid): webmail.warwick.net [204.255.24.104] not internal Oct 25 01:11:02 g2t0433g opendkim[17677]: (unknown-jobid): not authenticated Oct 25 01:11:02 g2t0433g opendkim[17677]: (unknown-jobid): no signing domain match for `warwick.net'
Oct 25 01:11:02 g2t0433g opendkim[17677]: (unknown-jobid): no signing subdomain match for `warwick.net'
Oct 25 01:11:02 g2t0433g postfix/qmgr[17833]: 2EAAF23004C: from=<peter***@warwick.net>, size=1987, nrcpt=1 (queue active) Oct 25 01:11:02 g2t0433g postfix/smtpd[6497]: disconnect from webmail.warwick.net[204.255.24.104]
Oct 25 01:11:03 g2t0433g amavis[6492]: (06492-09) Passed CLEAN, [204.255.24.104] [204.255.24.104] <peter***@warwick.net> -> <775eejom36ebi@xxx.com>, Message-ID: <CE130ED7-D498-4461-B076-E3B8AB55B462@warwick.net>, mail_id: rJ8M8oQHBzWt, Hits: 1.104, size: 2234, queued_as: 250 Ok, 946 ms Oct 25 01:11:03 g2t0433g postfix/lmtp[6585]: 2EAAF23004C: to=<775eejom36ebi@xxx.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=1.6, delays=0.6/0/0.01/0.95, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 Ok, id=06492-09, from MTA([127.0.0.1]:10030): 250 Ok) Oct 25 01:11:03 g2t0433g postfix/qmgr[17833]: 2EAAF23004C: removed
```

How to determine that such mail is genuine or SPAM?

Is there any rule on spamassassin that I can set that will discard such mails?

Right now I have added 'peter***@warwick.net' in my postfix 'main.cf' restriction list as follows:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/senderRestrictionList,  
  reject_unauth_destination,
  reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
  reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
  permit
```

Is it the right approach?

Please help

Thanks in advance

Ashish Sharma

Answer (score 1):

If you let the message queue up on your server (instead of rejecting it,) you should be able to do `sudo postcat -q <message id>` to view the message and its headers. This should let you determine if its spam or not.